# Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::languages does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am trying to attach a `languages` table with a `posts` table. I have already setup a `language_post` table with a `post_id` and a `language_id` column.  When I try to add **Post** with **languages**, it gives me this error as shown above.

Checked `App/Language.php`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Language extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
?>
```

Within `PostController`'s method, `public function store(Request $request)` is where I get this error

```
//above this all fields working perfectly
 $post->save();
        $post->languages()->attach($request->languages);
```

Comment: i think there is some problem with your calling because you are calling "languages" while your class name in  "Language"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you forget to do the same for the Post model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function languages()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Language')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```